# jQuery Modal Confirmation Error

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm working my way through some of the tutorials on the jQuery website, and I'm currently working on the 'Modal Confirmation Dialog'.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testdialog) page, but I can't seem to get the page to load without receiving the following error:

`Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 16`, which is this line in my code: `$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );`.

I'm really not sure why I'm receiving this, I've been through the source files and I think I have the links to the correct js and css files.

I know to most this may be a very basic and beginner error, but I'm beginner with jQuery, and I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/tzerb/PAg8N/

Comment: @tzerb thnak you for putting this together. Yes it works fine, so as in my comment later in this post, I suspect that I'm pointing to incorrect JS and CSS files. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply remove this line...

```
$("#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "destroy" );
```

or if you want that to work, put that line below of the dialog init... and change it to something like that..

(but it will surely remove the dialog functionality so simple remove it)

you don't need to put `:ui-dialog` there... 
you just had a selection error..

if its selected using id use `#`
and when you select using class use `.`

example

**if id**

```
<div id="dialog">a dialog msg</div>
<script>
$("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
</script>
```

**if class**

```
<div class="dialog">a dialog msg/div>
<script>
$(".dialog").dialog("destroy");
</script>
```

Comment: I think he can just remove the line completely.  The bug is in the example, not in the plug in.

Comment: Hi @Mahan, thank you for responding to my post. I've edited the line out, and as has been suggested, it unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. Kind regards

Comment: I meant the example he was using to do his code.  @IRHM  I did it in jsfiddle.net and it works fine in IE.

Comment: @tzerb, thnak you for helping me with this. It's strange because I'm using IE and I just continue to get the same error. Any ideas please? Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM: does the JS Fiddle demo posted, as a comment to your question, work? If it does, then the error is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes the JSFiddle demo works fine, so I suspect it may be that I'm pointing to incorrect JS and CSS fiels. Kind regards.

Comment: Hi all, I've sorted it. I was pointing to incorrect JS and CSS files. Thank you to all for your help. Kind regards.